# Какой создать датасет для классификации винтов по виду сверху?

Tags: изображения, машинное-обучение

Нужно создать датасет для CNN, классифицирующей винты по виду сверху. Прошу советы по созданию датасета:

- Как разнообразить примеры?
- Сколько фотографий понадобится?

[image: Пример получаемого фото]

Любые другие пояснения приветствуются.

Comment: Вопрос. Может быть, коль скоро у вас нет датасета, вам и не нужен он? Может воспользоваться opencv?

Comment: Какие виды винтов есть?

Comment: Я хочу комбинировать сеть и opencv, сеть значительно упростит работу.

Comment: Так у вас же нет датасета. Как она упростит работу? Задача неясна. Расскажите подробнее, что хотите сделать, что есть в наличии.

Comment: Нужно бесконтактно измерить шлиц и отбраковать плохие винты. Есть и плоские, и крестовые.

Comment: Что такое "плохие"? Прикрепите изображения, которые хотите фильтровать.

Comment: Плохой - с крестиком, у которого размеры выходят за допуски.

Comment: Вы ведете к тому, что нейросеть тут не нужна?

Comment: Я веду к тому, что Ваша задача не ясна. Кажется, что сбор датасета в Вашем случае намного более трудоёмкая задача, чем какие-нибудь детекторы Хафа и т.п. Все ли изображения аналогичны тому, что Вы привели? Бывают ли детали повёрнутыми иначе? Приведите пример невалидной детали